Screw modifier not mirroring the object I'm drawing
Why is this happening? I'm trying to model this chess piece with the screw modifier but for some reason this happens:


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101386/screw-modifier-problem https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253830/how-can-i-use-screw-modifier-right

"but for some reason this happens": What precisely is "this"? It looks like a profile is sweeped around the Y axis (it looks a bit angled, but hard to tell from the perspective). The Screw modifier does exactly this, sweeping a profile around a rotational axis - and in your case, the Y axis is chosen. What is it you actually expected it to do?

Screw modifier extrudes your geometry in steps while rotating it around object's origin point(or another chosen object called "Axis Object" in the properties of the modifier) on selected axis. So, although the resulting geometry has radial symmetry, it does not "mirror" the object and is not supposed to do that.
You should choose the axis for rotation:

In your case that would probably be Z if the object space matches global space.
You also have to make sure the geometry is appropriately positioned in relation to the object's origin point. You can do that by either moving the geometry in edit mode, or moving the origin point with Affect Only: Origins enabled:

All regular transform operations( G ,  R ,  S ) will then affect only origin.
